# Pandas Convert Data Type of List inside a Dictionary

Tags: pandas

I have the following data structure:

```
import pandas as pd 

names = {'A': [20, 5, 20], 
         'B': [18, 7, 13],
         'C': [19, 6, 18]}
```

I was able to convert the Data Type for A, B, C from an object to a string as follows:

```
df = df.astype({'Team-A': 'string', 'Team-B': 'string', 'Team-C': 'string'}, errors='raise')
```

How can I convert the data types in the list to float64?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the dictionary to a dataframe and then change the dataframe to float.

```
import pandas as pd
names = {'A': [20, 5], 
         'B': [18, 7],
         'C': [19, 6]}
df=pd.DataFrame(names)
df.astype('float64')
```

If you dont want to use dataframe you can do like this

```
names={k:[float(i) for i in v] for k,v in names.items()}
```